# Can Somebody tell me what's wrong with this codes?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I can't print the value of `$_POST` in my browser.
This the `form_methods.php`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Methods</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="formoutputpage.php">
            <p><input type="text" name="greeting" size="15"></p>
            <p><input type="text" name="name" size="15"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Salutation"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is the `formoutputpage.php`:

```
<?
    echo $_POST['greeting'];
    echo " ".$_POST['name'];
    echo "!";
?>
```

Comment: Does it echo anything at all, do you have short-tags enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this code is OK. Check whether there is any error which is not displayed.
So insert this code top of formoutputpage.php that exactly display all errors.

```
<?php
  ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

And check short tag is allowed. `<?` => `<?php`
Parse error may not be displayed depending on your configration.

Comment: ow! I got it! The short tag is not working! thank you!

Comment: So glad to work:)) Would you accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the "!" ?

if(false)
 openlink('http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag')
else
 echo 'i don\'t know then'

Comment: Cute, but please answer in plain English..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form Methods</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="formoutputpage.php">
            <input type="text" name="greeting" size="15" />
            <input type="text" name="name" size="15" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Salutation" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

formoutputpage.php

```
<?php
     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $_POST['greeting'] . " " . $_POST['name'] . "!";
     }else{
        //do whatever you want
     }
?>
```